Cross entropy loss for multi classification problem
I am handling a multi-class classification problem, with label in the following form [1333201000]
and the logit output of the model is in the form
([[ 0.4523,  0.0198, -0.1911, -0.0036],
[ 0.4917,  0.4316, -0.2846,  0.0774],
[ 0.4827,  0.2323, -0.2338,  0.2975],
[ 0.0017,  0.0069,  0.1721,  0.1800],
[ 0.2452,  0.0772, -0.3574,  0.1191],
[ 0.2852,  0.2769, -0.0884,  0.1215],
[ 0.0825,  0.2109, -0.3785,  0.0742],
[ 0.2253,  0.4560, -0.1529, -0.3226],
[ 0.4251,  0.0682, -0.1916, -0.2752],
[ 0.3496,  0.2189, -0.1748,  0.2128]])
and the CrossEntropyLoss I use is torch.nn.crossentropyloss, I have a problem that my problem is suitable for this loss function, and is this version of torch really similar to the crossentropy function:

What does it mean that you are of the form [1333201000], that the first outcome is category 1, the second is category 3, the last is category 0, etc?

yep, it stored a list of outcome as you said above

You have been given your labels in a bit of an obnoxious format, but that format can be untangled to give a list of labels, such as with Python code like the following.
mylist = [1333201000]                                       # This is what you have
categories = [int(category) for category in str(mylist[0])] # Make a list of labels
print(categories)

The Torch documentation suggests that having a list (maybe an np.array) of label indices like the categories variable is would be accepted.

The target that this criterion expects should contain either:

Then it says to give the values for your four classes as 0, 1, 2, and 3, exactly as the categories variable above gives.
Then the predictions give, for each true label in categories, the predicted probability of each category occurring. In a prediction problem, you want the true category to be predicted close to one and the others to be close to zero, but you may not always be so lucky.

thank for sharing to me, actually i wanna know that with category loss like above is it similar if using crossentropy loss for each element of list outcome
